# Repeat div inside an accordion class

Tags: php, jquery, css, laravel, accordion

I have an accordion div inside which I have another set of Div as follows

```
<div id="accordion">
  <div class="group">
    <h3>question 1
      <span class="draggable-handle"></span>
    </h3>
    <div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="ENTER QUESTION 1">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="file-upload col-md-4">
          <label for="upload-photo">Upload image/Video <span class="upload">upload</span></label>
          <input type="file" name="photo" id="upload-photo" />
        </div>
      </div>
      @if($surveytypeid == 2)
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-4 mb_20">
          <select class="custom-select">
            <option selected="">MULTIPLE CHOICE SINGLE SELECT</option>
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      @endif
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 mb_20"><b>ADD OPTIONS</b></div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="OPTION 1">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="OPTION 2">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-4 position-relative">
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="OPTION 3">
          <a class="add-option" href="" onclick="warning()"><img src="{{asset('admin/images/icn-add-option.png')}}" alt=""></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I need the div `class="group"` to get appended to accordion div by clicking a button. Currently I did it as follows:

```
<button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button"  id="addQuestion"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i>ADD QUESTION</button>
```

My script is as follows:

```
 $('#addQuestion').click(function() {

$("#accordion").append(
'<div class="group"><h3>question 1<span class="draggable-handle"></span></h3> <div><div class="form-group row"><div class="col-md-12"><input class="form-control" placeholder="ENTER QUESTION 1"></div></div><div class="form-group row"><div class="file-upload col-md-4"><label for="upload-photo">Upload image/Video <span class="upload">upload</span></label><input type="file" name="photo" id="upload-photo" /></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col-md-12 mb_20"><b>ADD OPTIONS</b></div></div><div class="form-group row"><div class="col-md-4"><input class="form-control" placeholder="OPTION 1"></div></div><div class="form-group row"><div class="col-md-4"><input class="form-control" placeholder="OPTION 2"></div> </div><div class="form-group row"><div class="col-md-4 position-relative"><input class="form-control" placeholder="OPTION 3"><a class="add-option" href=""  onclick="warning()"><img src="cn-add-option.png" alt=""></a></div></div></div></div>');
});
});
```

But now on click of the button, the elements are getting displayed into accordion class. But CSS is missing. No collapsible window appears.

This is how my accordion works right now. First one is already in the html and second one is loaded by button click.

[image: dynamically load accordion div]

Comment: `</div>` missing in accordion div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following code as button click event:

```
$('#addQuestion').click(function() {
    $(".group:last").after('<div class="group">' +
    '<h3>question 1<span class="draggable-handle"></span></h3>' + 
      '<div>' +
        '<div class="form-group row">' +
          '<div class="col-md-12">' +
            '<input class="form-control" placeholder="ENTER QUESTION 1">' +
          '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="form-group row">' +
          '<div class="file-upload col-md-4">' +
            '<label for="upload-photo">Upload image/Video <span class="upload">upload</span></label>' +
            '<input type="file" name="photo" id="upload-photo" />' +
          '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="row">' +
          '<div class="col-md-12 mb_20">' +
            '<b>ADD OPTIONS</b>' +
          '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="form-group row">   ' +
          '<div class="col-md-4">' +
            '<input class="form-control" placeholder="OPTION 1">' +
          '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="form-group row">' +
          '<div class="col-md-4">' +
            '<input class="form-control" placeholder="OPTION 2">' +
          '</div> ' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="form-group row">' +
          '<div class="col-md-4 position-relative">' +
            '<input class="form-control" placeholder="OPTION 3">' +
            '<a class="add-option" href=""  onclick="warning()"><img src="cn-add-option.png" alt=""></a>' +
          '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
'</div>'');
});
```

Comment: I have updated my question with screenshot of what I'm getting right now.

Comment: But still it comes same as in my screenshot.

Comment: Okay after the above line of code we need to add a little more. Within the click function add also
$(".group:last").accordion({
      collapsible: true,
      heightStyle: "content"
  });

This will work